# "duplicated RLS configuration" each time RLS is started inside VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-language-server

I upgraded my Rust environment via `rustup update` recently, then my VSCode reports an error each time I open my editor. Two repeated windows pop up at the bottom right corner of the editor, showing that

```
Duplicated RLS configuration: rustfmt_path:rustfmt_path,rustfmt_path,,
Source: Rust (rls) (Extension)
```

I can open VSCode's default settings.json and indeed find duplicated entries, but I'm not able to delete them.

Restarting the extension can reproduce the problem, and I don't even know if the plugin itself is working properly or not.

Comment: Do you have two Rust extensions installed and enabled by any chance?

Comment: Might be the case but I don't know which extension added duplicated entries in default settings.json

Comment: I have both rls and racer installed, is that a possible cause? Note this problem wasn't seen before, so it is more like a rust tool chain issue than vscode issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been through the same problem. I am not exactly sure of the proper solution but these workarounds have solved my problem.

1. Remove all VSCode extensions that are Rust-related.
2. Remove any Rust-related configuration in VSCode settings.json.
3. If you are using Linux and you have done a lot of playing around, sometimes `$HOME/.cargo/registry` may be corrupt, so remove that folder if it helps.
4. Restart VSCode.
5. Install these extensions in order:

   - Rust RLS official extension

     Do not install Rust kalitaalexey (Seems to be the conflicting cause).
   - Rust Assist extension.
   - vscode-rust-syntax extension.
   - vsc-rustfmt extension.
   - Cargo extension.
   - Better TOML

The combination of these extensions work OK for me. Specifically, the syntax formatting works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and saving the file automatically does that.

One last hint: Opening 2 Rust project folders in VSCode at the same time may cause an error message that states `Unable to find root directory`. Try to avoid that.

Comment: removing just **Rust kalitaalexey** extension did solve the same issue I have

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have two VS Code extensions installed that do the same thing. That was at least the problem in my case.

Uninstall the extension `Rust` by `kalitaalexey` and keep the "official" extension `Rust (rls)` maintained by the Rust Language development team.